# Windows 10 isn't shown in dual boot menu with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, grub, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 to different local disks. But on the booting window,  Windows 10 isn't showing after installing Ubuntu- there is only Ubuntu on the menu.

How do I enter Windows 10?

Note that when I installed Ubuntu it warned me that Windows 10 was installed with BIOS compatibility mode, but Ubuntu would install in UEFI mode. Nevertheless I have forced the install. Is it the reason that Windows 10 isn't shown?

Comment: Did you try `update-grub` in Ubuntu ?

Comment: no, how can I try it?

Comment: I don't no much about UEFI and Legacy Mode. I think It's related to BIOS. Even I faced the same issue in Dell Latitude 3450 laptop. After changing Setting in bios I was able to boot. OR boot into Ubuntu open terminal login as root and enter the command `update-grub`.

Comment: @max If I am not wrong, UEFI is the replacement for BIOS rather than Legacy Mode. UEFI is a more extensible standard for communicating with the hardware out of the box. UEFI can also directly control boot settings, hence it should allow to repair the boot options during runtime.
At least that's how I do it under Debian12.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install grub.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Use 'Recommended repair' option. For more details use [this official](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) Ubuntu document.